# Python: convert my_list = [ '[2,2]', '[0,3]' ] to my_list = [ [2,2], [0,3] ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list:

```
my_list = [ '[2,2]', '[0,3]' ]
```

I want to convert it into

```
my_list = [ [2,2], [0,3] ]
```

Is there any easy way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to avoid `eval` is to parse them as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json


my_list = [ '[2,2]', '[0,3]' ]
new_list = [json.loads(item) for item in my_list]
```

This would not only avoid the possible negative risks of `eval` on data that you don't control but also give you errors for content that is not valid lists.

Comment: Thank you. This works and appears to be faster than ast.literal_eval.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [eval(x) for x in my_list]
```

But beware: `eval()` is a potentially dangerous function, always validate its input.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` would be good alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import ast
my_list = [ '[2,2]', '[0,3]' ]
res = list(map(ast.literal_eval, my_list))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2], [0, 3]]
```

You can read these:

1. [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)
2. [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Comment: Thank you. This works. But seems to be slower than the solution based on json